Why is my react native expo app not receiving the context from the AuthProvider?
I have been having this issue for quite some time now, I tried everything I could to fix it, but nothing worked.
Here's the AuthContext.tsx contents:
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  ReactNode,
} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import * as SecureStore from "expo-secure-store";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";
import { jwtDecode } from "jwt-decode";

type AuthContextType = {
  onRegister: (username: string, password: string) => Promise<any>;
  onLogin: (username: string, password: string) => Promise<any>;
  onLogout: () => Promise<void>;
  authState: AuthStateType;
  authData: AuthDataType;
};

type AuthStateType = {
  token: string | null;
  authenticated: boolean;
};

type AuthDataType = {
  id: number | null;
  username: string | null;
  iat: number | null;
  exp: number | null;
};

const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType | undefined>(undefined);

const TOKEN_KEY = "authToken";
const API_URL = "https://anonytext-backend.vercel.app/api";

const useAuth = (): AuthContextType => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState<AuthStateType>({
    token: null,
    authenticated: false,
  });
  const [authData, setAuthData] = useState<AuthDataType>({
    id: null,
    username: null,
    iat: null,
    exp: null,
  });

  const register = async (username: string, password: string): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      return await axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/register`, {
        username,
        password,
      });
    } catch (e: any) {
      return {
        error: true,
        message: e.response?.data?.message || "An error occurred",
      };
    }
  };

  const login = async (username: string, password: string): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      const result = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/login`, {
        username,
        password,
      });
      setAuthState({ token: result.data.access, authenticated: true });
      axios.defaults.headers.common[
        "Authorization"
      ] = `Bearer ${result.data.access}`;
      await SecureStore.setItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY, result.data.access);

      return result;
    } catch (e: any) {
      return {
        error: true,
        message: e.response?.data?.message || "An error occurred",
      };
    }
  };

  const logout = async (): Promise<void> => {
    await SecureStore.deleteItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY);
    axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "";
    setAuthState({ token: null, authenticated: false });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadToken = async () => {
      const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync(TOKEN_KEY);

      if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        setAuthState({ token, authenticated: true });
        setAuthData(jwtDecode(token));
      }
      setLoading(false);
    };

    loadToken();
  }, []);

  const contextData: AuthContextType = {
    onRegister: register,
    onLogin: login,
    onLogout: logout,
    authState,
    authData,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData}>
      {!loading ? children : <ActivityIndicator size={20} />}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AuthProvider, useAuth };

Which looks pretty solid and should be working, but i keep getting:

(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Warning: Error: useAuth must be used within an AuthProvider

According to this message, the useAuth hook is supposed to be used in a child element wrapped with the AuthProvider Context, which is exactly what I did here:
App.tsx:
import React from "react";
import { AuthProvider } from "@/context/AuthContext";
import RootLayout from "./app/_layout";
import { NotifierWrapper } from "react-native-notifier";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

// Wrap the entire app with AuthProvider
export default function App() {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <NotifierWrapper>
        <AuthProvider>
          <RootLayout />
        </AuthProvider>
      </NotifierWrapper>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

And the ./app/_layout.tsx:
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { Slot, Redirect } from "expo-router";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { useAuth } from "@/context/AuthContext";
import { ActivityIndicator } from "react-native-paper";

// Prevent the splash screen from hiding until the font is loaded
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const { authState } = useAuth(); // Directly access authState from context

  console.log("Auth Context State:", authState);

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    FontAwesome6Pro: require("../assets/fonts/fa-regular-400.ttf"),
    FontAwesome6ProLight: require("../assets/fonts/fa-light-300.ttf"),
    FontAwesome6ProSolid: require("../assets/fonts/fa-solid-900.ttf"),
  });

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return null; // Keep splash screen visible while loading fonts
  }

  // If authState is undefined, don't attempt to render protected routes yet
  if (authState === undefined) {
    return <ActivityIndicator size={20} />; // Show loading indicator if auth state is undefined
  }

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
      {authState.authenticated ? <Slot /> : <Redirect href="/login" />}
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

Which should be working caused I wrapped the RootLayout with the AuthProvider. Is there something I did wrong?
